# SwiftUI - Strange Animation

Tags: animation, swiftui

I have an image for a button. Intended result is so that when I click on the button/image, a list of items appear below it. However, for some reason the image itself shrinks upon clicking. How would I prevent the image from shrinking and just having the items populate below the image?

```
struct HabitGroups: View {
    var imageName: String
    var textOverlay: String
    var listOfHabits: [String]
    @Binding var selectedHabitList: [String]
    @Binding var enoughHabits: Bool

    @State var showHabits = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.showHabits.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                Image(self.imageName)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(minWidth: 300, minHeight: 100)
                    .overlay(ImageOverlay(textOverlay: self.textOverlay), alignment: .bottom)
            }
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

            if self.showHabits {
                ForEach(self.listOfHabits, id: \.self) { habit in
                    AddHabitButtons(habit: habit, selectedHabitList: self.$selectedHabitList, enoughHabits: self.$enoughHabits)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Before Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bChhK.png)

[After Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AGot.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to many items below image to fit without resizing everything on screen (as you placed everything in on VStack), so image shrinks as it is .resizalbe.

Possible solution would be to embed habits into scroll view, like below

```
if self.showHabits {
  ScrollView {                                            // << here !!
    ForEach(self.listOfHabits, id: \.self) { habit in
        AddHabitButtons(habit: habit, selectedHabitList: self.$selectedHabitList, enoughHabits: self.$enoughHabits)
    }
  }
}
```

another alternate is to make image fixed by height, but in this case shown habits will push it up off screen. However intended behavior is not clear, anyway here it is

```
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)           // << here !!
```

Comment: I tried the second one. Did the trick. Thank you so much!